# ffserver / ffmpeg error rasperberry pi

Tags: tcp, ffmpeg, ffserver

on rasperberry pi 2 (jessie) with web cam i run on terminal:
    ffserver start & avconv -f video4linux2 -r 25 -i /dev/video0 -f alsa -ac 1 -i hw:1,0 http://localhost:8090/feed1.ffm

```
i get this error:

The driver changed the time per frame from 1/25 to 1/30
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
Duration: N/A, start: 91550.051357, bitrate: 147456 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 147456 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #1.0 : mono
Input #1, alsa, from 'hw:1,0':
Duration: N/A, start: 1508451910.083274, bitrate: 768 kb/s
Stream #1:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 768 kb/s`enter code here`
[tcp @ 0x15ca6c0] Connection to tcp://localhost:8090 failed (Connection refused), trying next address
Thu Oct 19 23:25:10 2017 127.0.0.1 - - [GET] "/feed1.ffm HTTP/1.1" 200 4175
[tcp @ 0x15dba80] Connection to tcp://localhost:8090 failed (Connection refused), trying next address
[mpeg1video @ 0x15df560] MPEG-1/2 does not support 3/1 fps
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> mp2 (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (rawvideo (native) -> mpeg1video (native))
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:2 (pcm_s16le (native) -> wmav2 (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:3 (rawvideo (native) -> msmpeg4v3 (msmpeg4))
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Thu Oct 19 23:25:10 2017 127.0.0.1 - - [POST] "/feed1.ffm HTTP/1.1" 200 0
anyone can help me to solve ? i want to heard audio too and image on stream??
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46858117/tcp-connection-refused-when-using-ffserver-ffmpeg-and-errors)